# Entity Framework Diagram with Schemas

Tags: entity-framework-5

We have a database already created, we use DatabaseFirst, but we need to add some other new schemas into the database. I don't want to create new tables in EF and update the databasse from the model. I just want to apply some changes without touching the rest. Is there any way to keep the database schema as a diagram only? also is there any way to show the schema name and be able to group tables by schema filter it and eventually moved into another diagram to keep many diagram separably by schema?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this same thing, but failed to find a way using VS. You can certainly modify any SQL database using SQL statements, but it sounds like you want to use many visual models, and apply them selectively. I use Modelright because it allows advanced schema manipulation, and you can highlight tables and their relationships, then just generate that specific SQL, then copy and paste the statements. I also change the color schemes (no pun intended) of different tables to keep track of present and future, etc. It also generates directly to the database, reverse engineers, etc. It costs a lot. Warning though, I couldn't reverse engineer CE 4.0.

I believe Enterprise Architect also does a lot of this for SQL, although primarily an all-in-one UML tool, if EA does what you need, maybe better because has cheaper version and great UML tool, also. It won't have the advanced graphics.

If someone knows how get VS2012 to do some modeling tricks, please jump in.